# Most Efficient Data Load and Preparation for PowerBi Boolean Attribute

Tags: performance, optimization, model, powerbi, dax

Can anyone with experience in large PowerBi data models tell me which is the most efficient approach for the following use case?

I created a number of views on SQL server with bit attributes of 1 and 0 that denote true or false. Personally, I like using this approach as it makes it easier for aggregations. However, in PowerBi, I am designing reports for business users who would prefer a format of “yes” and “no.” To make this conversion, I am needing to decide from the following approaches:

1. Create a separate look up table with a yes/no description field and make the relation(s).
2. Create a measure with DAX that makes this transformation on the fly.
3. Create a calculated column with DAX.

Because my data sets have millions of rows, I need to choose the approach that minimizes compute.

Anyone have this issue before? What approach worked best?